# Argument list unpacking

Tags: terraform

I'm currently trying to retrieve the max value contained in a list, but the `max()` builtin accept a variable number of floats instead of a single list.

```
variable "my_list" {
    default = [1, 2]
}

output map_out {
    value = "${max(var.my_list)}"
}

Error: output.map_out: At column 3, line 1: max: argument 1 should be type float, got type list in:
```

There's a way to accomplish this?
I think I need something similar to the argument list unpacking in Python, but I don't know how to do this in Terraform.

Answer (score 2):

Function "map" does not accept list, it only accept individual floats.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#max-float1-float2-

so only that format will work.

```html
output map_out {
    value = "${max(var.my_list[0],var.my_list[1])}"
}
```

if the number of values can differ - may be sort will work instead.